# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I m using JBPM jar to follow some process. Previously we did some code change in jar and build using Malven and it works fine. Now we did again some code change and build using Ant script. but it throws Exception like

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.hibernate.engine.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:22)
at org.hibernate.engine.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:44)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:44)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:124)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceServiceFactory.getSessionFactory(DbPersistenceServiceFactory.java:97)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceService.getSessionFactory(DbPersistenceService.java:95)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceService.getSession(DbPersistenceService.java:99)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceService.getGraphSession(DbPersistenceService.java:341)
at org.jbpm.JbpmContext.getGraphSession(JbpmContext.java:571)
at org.jbpm.JbpmContext.newProcessInstanceForUpdate(JbpmContext.java:417)
at com.k2.process.adapter.jbpm.JBPMAdapter.createNewProcessInstance(JBPMAdapter.java:79)
at com.k2.process.ProcessAgentManager.createNewProcessInstance(ProcessAgentManager.java:45)
at com.k2.process.control.ProcessController.createNewProcess(ProcessController.java:153)
at com.k2.process.control.ProcessController.createNewProcess(ProcessController.java:90)
at com.k2.process.ProcessAgentBean.createProcess(ProcessAgentBean.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:350)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:960)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor644.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocalMarshalled(InvokerInterceptor.java:295)
at org.jboss.invocation.MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.invoke(MarshallingInvokerInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
at $Proxy503.createProcess(Unknown Source)

 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at com.k2.util.HibernateQuery.execute(HibernateQuery.java:32)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     ... 209 more
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR] Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57fe7d:998:4e703d1b:201 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57fe7d:998:4e703d1b:201 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:94)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:69)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     ... 223 more
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR] Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -3f57fe7d:998:4e703d1b:201 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:304)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:842)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:88)
2011-09-14 11:13:56,457 ERROR [http-192.168.1.131-18080-1] [STDERR]     ... 225 more
```

There is no any change in build flow.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/JbpmDS</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Above is my hibernate mapping.
And here is my line from where exception is generated

```
sessionFactory=hibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Thank You in adavance.

Comment: Did you get a stack trace? If so, post that; the exception message alone is not enough.

Comment: Hi Vineet, Have updated my Question with Exception.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that the updated exception is the cause of the originally posted `GenericJDBCException`. I do not see the older exception in the new stack trace.

Comment: Hi Vineet, Sorry for last updated. Now I have posted GenericJDBCException.

Comment: You might want to read [this article](http://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/transaction-is-not-active-txtransactionimple-ac-basicaction/).

Comment: Thanks Vineet, Thank You Very Very much......Link which u suggested, really really helps. Problem was, there was one property file was missed in newly created jar. It's not showing any exception for tat file, Just throw exception for Hibernate Transaction. Thanks again Vineet....

Answer (score 13):

This is being posted, to serve as an useful answer for the question.

The exception `javax.resource.ResourceException` with message: `Transaction is not active` does not imply that the transaction has failed because of some inability to start a transaction. Rather, an uncaught exception was thrown in application code that resulted in termination of the existing transaction. When a subsequent transactional activity was attempted, it failed with the specified exception, as the transaction associated with the thread was no longer active.

The fix in such an event is to fix the cause of the original exception that resulted in the inactive transaction. This may be done by catching the exception using an overly broad exception handler (that catches `Exception` or `Throwable`) to determine the root cause. Fixing the root cause, will result in the exception not being thrown, with the desired effect of ensuring that the transaction will be active when a transactional activity is performed.

Answer (score -2):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        itcomtech123+
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.92:1433;DatabaseName=UFDATA_105_2011;
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    </property>
```

You may be less information on these configuration。

Comment: I have configured my connection in DS file in JBoss server. So no need to define in .cfg file. Just set <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/connectionDS</property>